# Storage the image in the database or the image path?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, file-upload, upload, image-uploading

I have a database with a table for some information about the users and I need to allow the user to upload some images. This is for a simple website the idea is upload the file to a folder in the server and storage in the database the path to the image in the server. There is going to be just a few images.

What it's a better way storage the path in the database, and the image in a folder in the sever, or storage the image as a binary content in the database??

Comment: It entirely depends on your system really. I'm afraid this question is primarily opinion based and, as such, is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I agree with @DavidG above.  As anecdotal evidence, I work for a company that has seen it's growth lead from primarily housing image data as a blob to storing image URI as departments were added and a consistent company-wide file share became available. That said, 
 because we've prioritized db space for the most part, doesn't also mean that your specific requirements may require you to do the same.

Comment: These two ways are both ok. My suggestion is to store images into sql database if there are not too many images, otherwise, it's better store them into file system because you can store them no matter how many there are.